# How to add logo to router view transition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In the App.vue, I wrapped fade transition around `<router-view>`. How to add logo to the white fade-in screen that shows while changing subpages?

The simplified code of my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="site-content">
            <header></header>
            <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                <router-view/>
            </transition>
            <footer></footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    /*---*/
</script>

<style>    
    /*---transition---*/
    .fade-enter-active,
    .fade-leave-active {
        transition-duration: 0.3s;
        transition-property: opacity;
        transition-timing-function: ease;  
    }

    .fade-enter,
    .fade-leave-active {
        opacity: 0;
    }    
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is give every "page" a style of `position: relative` and then include  layer to the back of the pages that contains your logo:

```js
var firstPage = {
    template: `
        <div class="page">
            <router-link :to="{name:'page2'}">page 2</router-link>
        </div>
    `,
}
var secondPage = {
    template: `
        <div class="page">
            <router-link :to="{name:'page1'}">page 1</router-link>
        </div>
    `,
}

var routes = [
  { name: 'page1', path: '/', component: firstPage },
  { name: 'page2', path: '/first', component: secondPage }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: "#template",
    router,
})
```

```css
.app, html, body {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


/*---transition---*/
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-timing-function: ease;  
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}    



.page {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<!-- router -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<template id="template">
    <div class="app">
        <div class="logo">
            TEST LOGO
        </div>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view/>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

While this looks like a bunch of code, most of it is actually boilerplate to setup vue-router so I can show the example to you.

During normal operation, the page is fully on top, and you cannot see the logo below it. When you then change pages, the current page fades out, so the logo becomes more visible as its located below it, and then the logo fades out again as the new page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think it will solve the problem.